# How to perform a segue when a UILocalNotification is fired?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uilocalnotification

I am making an app with multiple schedule alarms in the future. The design is that a Local Notification will fire, then when the user opens the app any time after this notification (either through Notification Action or just by tapping the icon on the home screen), the app will automatically show an Alarm view controller, which the user interacts with.

I know I can just call on a function with performSegueWithIdentifier with the Notification Action feature, but I would really like a comprehensive method that covers the case when the user ignores the notification, then launches the app with other methods.

Thank you for your help!